# prove that the sum of dot products of a side and its median in a triangle is 0

Tags: geometry, vectors

$\vec {AP}, \vec {BQ}$ and $\vec {CR}$ are medians in triangle $ABC$.
Prove: $\vec {AB} \cdot \vec {CR} + \vec {BC} \cdot \vec {AP} + \vec {CA} \cdot \vec{BQ}=0$

I tried the following, but could not get to anywhere from here:
expanding the dot products using $\vec u \cdot \vec v = |\vec u||\vec v|cos(\theta)$
using the fact that a median splits the segment to two equal parts
using the fact that the three medians of a triangle meet in a single point which divides each median in a $2:1$ proportion

Comment: not really, Im asking for the sum of dot products not vector sum of medians

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\vec{CR}=\frac{\vec{CA}+\vec{CB}}{2},~\vec{AP}=\frac{\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}}{2},~\vec{BQ}=\frac{\vec{BA}+\vec{BC}}{2}$$

Plug into the LHS to replace $\vec{CR},~\vec{AP},~\vec{BQ}$ and simplify. Note, for example: $\vec{AB}=-\vec{BA}$

Comment: thank you, it worked. but now how do I prove that $\vec {CR} = \frac {\vec {CA}+\vec {CB}} {2}$?

Comment: For example, if you want to prove $\vec{CR}$, you make it into a Parallelogram, $ABCD$, so the median $\vec{CR}$ is just half of the diagonal $\vec{CD}$. And diagonal $\vec{CD}=\vec{CA}+\vec{CB}$ @mathguy